# Get file in folder directory based off first letter using C# console application

Tags: c#, console-application

I normally do not use `C#` and so I don't know the specific keywords to google or look up here on SO, so this may or may not be a duplicate.

I am using code from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4cyf24ss(v=vs.110).aspx and set up some test files named.

**A-test.dbf**

**B-test.dbf**

**C-test.dbf**

I am trying to get all .dbf files that start with "A" using `.GetFiles("A?.dbf")`

Here is the code I have, the first console print is showing all the files and the second should only print the files starting with an "A" but it is printing nothing.

```
        var d = 1;
        var e = 1;
        DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\temp");
        Console.WriteLine("No search pattern returns:");
        foreach (var fi in di.GetFiles())
        {

            Console.WriteLine(d +" "+fi.Name);
            d++;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Search pattern test?.dbf returns:");
        foreach (var fi in di.GetFiles("A?.dbf"))
        {

            Console.WriteLine(e + " " + fi.Name);
            e++;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("END Search pattern test?.dbf returns:");
```

Comment: Do you mean "A*.dbf" ?

Comment: `.GetFiles("A*.dbf")`

Comment: ? is a wildcard that only matches one character, * will match more than one character.

Comment: 3 comments with the same idea, I bet you all are right. I will try right now

Comment: Yep, That did it. Thank you!

Comment: so in the example it had a `*something*` does that mean anything before and after "something"?

Comment: It depends on the context, but yes, it could. It could also be used as an emphasis. `*` is fairly universally known as a wildcard representing 0-n instances of any character. The sequence: `*tar` would match the sequences: `tar`, `star`, but would NOT match `tarp`, `starter`, etc... if you used `*tar*`, that would match `tar`, `star`, `tarp`, and `starter`, however it could also be used to show emphasis on the word tar, just as making it bold, as in **tar** would do.